# adding Pardot website tracker script to my website

Tags: pardot

Pardot allows you to add campaign and customize your page view scoring. However, I need to add the Pardot tracker a website. I worked with different platforms before such as Marketo, they give you one that you can generate through the admin. How can I generate Pardot web tracker?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardot generates new tracking code for each campaign that is setup in the tool. Pardot has the concept of 'source campaign' so a prospect will always be associated to the first campaign they interact with. If the tracking code is a prospects first interaction, it will be that campaign they are associated with.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is follow the Pardot documentation on this:

http://help.pardot.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2133733-implementing-tracking-code

> 1. Navigate to Marketing > Campaigns.
> 2. Click on the name of the campaign
>      whose tracking you'd like to include on your website. The default is
>      Website Tracking campaign.
> 3. Once the campaign's main screen appears,
>      click on the View tracking code link.
> 4. Copy and paste the generated JavaScript code right before the close body tag on your HTML pages. The close body tag will be located
>      within a few lines of the end of the HTML page.